# What's the purpose of having a DTO going into a service?

Tags: design-patterns

Let's say this application has a `User` and each user must have a `firstName` and a `lastName`.  We could simply call the service with two strings from the controller (method A):

```
class UserController {
    function createUser(Request req) {
        userService.createUser(req.firstName, req.lastName)
    }
}
```

or we could pass it in a DTO (method B):

```
class UserController {
    function createUser(Request req) {
        dto = new UserDTO(req.firstName, req.lastName)
        userService.createUser(dto)
    }
}
```

The service method would perform validation, and talk to the repository for persistence of the new object.  And it seems like method B is just extra code to write and maintain.

If the service's contract changes (e.g. an email is now required to create a user):

- With method A you'd have to update the service's `createUser` method to accept a new string.  All code calling the service method would need to be updated.
- With method B, the method to create the DTO would need to be updated, and all code calling the DTO's constructor would have to be updated.

Why would a service method want to accept a DTO instead of explicitly listing out its params?

Comment: Where does this example come from?    The example seems so over-simplified and contrived, that without any additional context there's simply not enough information.   If this is a contrived example (such as from a tutorial) then it's likely just for illustrative purposes.  Without additional context the question really isn't answerable, as any answer can only be based on guesswork about where the code is from or how it fits whatever the author was trying to achieve. Otherwise, taken out of context, both examples are freely interchangeable.

Comment: I didn't think typing more parameters would affect anyone's answers.  Are you saying that more paramaters would affect your answer?  At its root the question is only about when a DTO is appropriate when calling a service method.

Comment: I'm saying that more context about the code would affect the decision making, particularly the structure of the overall system/codebase.   DTOs (Data Transfer Object) are for external boundaries/interfaces where stability of the interface matters to code which uses it (e.g. an external system/process),    but the given example doesn't obviously appear to be an external boundary, so it seems to be an unnecessary use of a DTO  (Indeed, it appears to me that `Request` is a DTO so the example seems like a case of [YAGNI](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/Yagni.html)).

Answer (score 1):

A DTO is a Grouping - Some might say this is an "Abstraction" (others will argue with that), so I will stick with "Grouping".

It is possible to argue that the Grouping improves; consistency, readability, auditablility and security. The crux of this argument being that it is possible to see what fields are being sent and received simply by looking at the DTO class - one doesn't need to review all processing code to see which fields are being used.

However the first point (consistency) deserves some extra review. I typically define three objects/groupings to handle the various cases:

- An `IdReference` (this is just an object with two fields an `Id` and `Name`).
- A Read Object (used for GETs)
- A Write Object (used for both POST and PUT).

If I had an Order, I might use the `IdReference` to reference each Product from the line items or to reference the User that the order belonged to. These references would only be used in the Read object as the Write object will only have `Id`s.

Additionally the "Read" object has three additional fields: The primary key (`Id`), `CreateTimestamp` and `UpdateTimestamp` that are not present in the write object. This is because the API/client is not allowed to (directly) update any of these fields (the `UpdateTimestamp` is indirectly updated).

I typically generate the Web (Read and Write) objects from an OpenAPI spec, then use a standard parser (such as Jackson) to handle the serialization. Hence I don't have to pay the (Developer/maintenance) cost of mapping incoming parameters as your code does.

Overall, this means that:

- The (OpenAPI) documentation exactly matches the code.
- All endpoints use consistent naming (since they re-use the same set of objects)
- I don't have to repeat the same (largely identical) code between the POST and PUT logic (only a tiny bit of code where the ORM is used changes).

> Why would a service method want to accept a DTO instead of explicitly
> listing out its params?

In a two model solution (Web and DB only) the benefits come from the consistence of the web tier - it's just easier to pass the web model to the application logic - rather than breaking out the fields.

If you add a third model (specific to the App logic) you can now support multiple revisions of the API. As the code for both API v1 and v2 can have different "mappings" to the App model.

Note: With good tooling, it is a trivial refactor to add a 3rd "App model" to an existing app so I usually start with a 2 model solution and only refactor if/when I need to support multiple API versions.

Answer (score 1):

> And it seems like method B is just extra code to write and maintain.

Changing contracts results in much larger and more risky refactors than changing a DTO.

Decoupling and abstractions have well-known tradeoffs. Complexity and extra code to maintain. But done right, limits the places where to do the changes, limiting the blast radius.

However, all of this is contextual.

If your service belongs to a library, widely implemented by hundreds or thousands of applications on the internet, the worse you can do is to change a  contract. You will rather prefer to expand it. You will add new contracts and deprecate (or not) the old ones. But at a certain point in time, if you have too many contracts cluttering your API, you will have reached the point where *"solution A is just extra code to write and maintain."*. Moreover, you might have encouraged developers to find an alternative with a much cleaner API and more convenient backward compatibility policies.

You will find the above to be less plausible if contracts don't change. Or, if changes are not breaking changes.

Now, imagine this

```js
interface CreateUserRequest {
    String firstName();
    String lastName();
    String email();
}
//The mapping is solved somewhere else out of the controller. For example, by the framework (or by the programming language itself).
class UserDTO implements CreateUserRequest {
    UserDTO(String firstName, String lastName){ ... }
    UserDTO(String firstName, String lastName, String email){ ... }
}

//consumer code remains as is
function createUser(CreateUserRequest req) {
  userService.createUser(req)
}
```

You can make it even more abstract if you introduce the concept of *tolerant readers*.

```js
class Request {
    Map parameters;
    Request(Map parameters){...}
    String getStringParameter(String path){ ... }
    Number getNumericParameter(String path){ ... }
}

//old code remains as is
function createUser(CreateUserRequest req) {
  userService.createUser(req)
}
```

Someone may argue that B (or my B options) won't be backwards compatible if `email` is required. Fair enough. The main difference is I don't make consumers immediately responsible for tackling their code. I have a chance to handle the issue from my service, which allows me to offer a window for consumers to adapt their code. In other words, I don't turn changes into compilation errors.

Runtime errors are not better per se, but they are, programmatically,  easier to handle. Plus, they don't break (necessarily) the development or the delivery cycle.

As you may guess, it's a matter of tradeoffs. Every design decision is. You choose what tradeoffs are more suitable in the current context.

Answer (score 0):

> Why would a service method want to accept a DTO instead of explicitly listing out its params?

A common reason is if the structure of the object is not known ahead of time. This could be the case with for example logging objects, where maybe the datetime and source might be known, but everything else about the data structure is unknown. The service might then take three objects:

1. Datetime
2. Source
3. Data transfer object containing all the relevant logging fields

Comment: If the language supports variadic parameters, would this point be moot?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the assumption is that there will be more than just few parameters being passed around. When it becomes a choice between a function with many parameters and DTO with many fields, the choice becomes obvious.

And in cases with just few parameters, it is good practice to be consistent with API design. So you will use a DTO even in such simple cases.

Comment: What is it about having many fields that makes it an obvious choice to use a DTO?  I personally fail to see the difference; the service method would have many parameters or the constructor would have the exact same parameters--and the constructor is also a method.

Answer (score 0):

There are several (in part overlapping) reasons:

- reduce the number of input or output parameters
- separation of concerns, you typically (especially in multi-tiered systems) not want your internal data structures to leak to other layers (let alone external systems) as that makes changes more difficult
- make the API more readable

For small, contrived, examples like yours this may seem overkill. But when you get into systems made up of many modules, maintained by several teams, with different release cycles, and tens of thousands or even millions of lines of code, it becomes essential to do such things.

For example a legacy system I've been working on lately (several hundred thousand lines of code) fails to do this in several places, leading to method calls between the frontend and backend that sometimes have over a dozen parameters. This makes it very hard to read what's going on. It also means that changes in the parameters of those calls affect a LOT of code, even if the new parameters being added are optional and only need to be filled by a single call to the method that you're changing and can be ignored by all others.

Comment: "sometimes have over a dozen parameters. This makes it very hard to read what's going on" Please explain why calling a service with a dozen params is different than constructing an object with a dozen params

Comment: @user430236 it should be obvious, long lines are harder to read than short ones, ESPECIALLY as you start messing up the order of method parameters

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, this boils down to "Why have an object (with many member fields) instead of a function with many parameters?". One might take it even further and ask "Why have objects instead of many primitives?".

First, the comparison in your question is simplified to the point of being silly - or at least making the DTO look a bit silly. The benefit of calling a constructor with *X* parameters and then passing the object to a function, over just passing those *X* parameters to the function, is indeed questionable, though not non-existent. An object can collect the logic for default parameters, validation, how to represent it in logs, deriving some values from others, etc.. But mainly, in my opinion, an object can be passed in as a parameter, reused in multiple calls, or created in a way different from just calling the constructor with all parameters.

Some alternatives to your "Method B" that might help things click:

```js
// A factory function doesn't really make sense in this simple case
class UserController {
    function createUser(Request req) {
        dto = UserDTO.fromRequest(req)
        userService.createUser(dto)
    }
}
```

```js
// A builder is useful (in languages which don't support named parameters) when you have a long parameter list
class UserController {
    function createUser(Request req) {
        dto = new UserDTOBuilder()
          .firstName(req.firstName)
          .lastName(req.lastName)
          .build();
        userService.createUser(dto)
    }
}
```

```js
// "Accidental" sharing can be a horrible idea. Reuse responsibly.
class UserController {
    function createUser(Request req) {
        dto = new UserDTO(req.firstName, req.lastName)
        userService.createUser(dto)
        welcomeService.sendGreeting(dto)
    }
}
```